# WINCE problem LoadLibraryEx

Tags: dll, windows-ce

I am using a WINCE framework for development called WINDEV.

This framework has some DLLs that are to be loaded, but on some WINCE platforms, the loading (tested with a c program with the LoadLibraryEx instruction) does not work ....

The results vary from one platform to another ....

What are the hypothesis to be checked ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What does exactly mean "*does not work*"?

According to MSDN, LoadLibraryEx on failure returns NULL, and "To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Some ideas:  
- is the DLL you are trying to load in the same directory of the executable?  
- is the DLL a valid Windows CE binary?  
- does LoadLibraryEx work if you try to load some known system DLL?

Sorry, without more details I cannot think of anything more.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows CE is a modular OS not all Windows CE platforms include all the components. It might be that your Dll is dependent on one of these components and thus fails to load.

As Benedetto suggested, get the last error and add the information to the question.

You can also use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what Dlls your library depends on so you can check whether they are available on the non cooperatives platforms.